# Importing terraform aws_iam_policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to import a terraform aws_iam_policy that gets automatically added by automation I don't own. The import seems to work but once I run a terraform plan I get the following error

```
* aws_iam_policy.mypolicy1: "policy": required field is not set
```

I'm running the terraform import as follows.

```
terraform import aws_iam_policy.mypolicy1 <myarn>
```

Here is my relevant terraform config

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "mypolicy1" {

}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "mypolicy1_attachment`" {
    role       = "${aws_iam_role.myrole1.name}"
    policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.mypolicy1.arn}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "myrole1" {
     name = "myrole1"
     assume_role_policy = "${file("../policies/ecs-role.json")}"
}
```

I double checked that the terraform.tfstate included the policy i'm trying to import. Is there something else I'm missing here?

Comment: As ydaetskcoR has already pointed out, you need to add terraform configuration to "create" the existing resource, as well as adding the existing resource to the state file. You may find [terraforming](https://github.com/dtan4/terraforming) a useful tool to help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a relatively elegant, and universal work-around to address Amazon's poor implementation of the *import IAM policy* capability.  The solution does NOT require that you reverse engineer Amazon, or anybody else's, implementation of the "*aws_iam_policy*" resource that you want to import.

There are two steps.

1. Create an *aws_iam_policy* resource definition that has a "lifecycle" argument, with an *ignore_changes* list. There are three fields in the *aws_iam_policy* resource that will trigger a replacement: policy, description and path.  Add these three fields to the *ignore_changes* list.
2. Import the external IAM policy, and attach it to the resource definition that you created in your resource file.

**Resource file** (ex: *static-resources.tf*)

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "MyLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole" {
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
    ignore_changes = [policy, path, description]
  }
  policy = jsonencode({})
}
```

**Import Statement**: Using the arn of the IAM policy that you want to import, import the policy and attach it to your resource definition.

```
terraform import aws_iam_policy.MyLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
```

The magic is the fields that you need to add to the *ignore_changes* list, and adding a place-holder for the required "*policy*" argument.  Since this is a required field, Terraform won't let you proceed without it, even though this is one of the fields that you told Terraform to ignore any changes to.

Note: If you use *modules*, you will need to add "module.." to the front on your resource reference.  For example

```
terraform import module.static.aws_iam_policy.MyLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
```

Answer (score 5):

You still need to provide the required fields in the Terraform configuration for the plan to work.

If you remove the `aws_iam_policy` resource from your configuration and run a plan after importing the policy you should see that Terraform wants to destroy the policy because it is in the state file but not in the configuration.

Simply setup your `aws_iam_policy` resource to match the imported policy and then a plan should show no changes.

Comment: Thanks. The documentation is really confusing about how this is supposed to work.